# JS: Make checkboxes disabled if select is default value?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of checkboxes from

```
<input type="checkbox" name="parts_hoses" id="parts-cb1" value="1">
```

through `id="parts-cb6"`

I have a select box of `#send-product`

```
                            <select name="send_product" id="send-product">
                                <option value="wall-mounted" selected>Wall-mounted (Default)</option>
                                <option value="freestanding">Freestanding</option>
                                <option value="third_party">Third Party</option>
                            </select>
```

that when it is on its default value, "wall-mounted", the checkboxes are enabled (as they are by default), but when I switch that to another option in the list... I'd like to disable the checkboxes.

Here is my JS so far (doesn't work):

```
  function switchProduct() {
    var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id^="parts-cb"]');
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('send-product');
    if (selectBox.value == 'wall-mounted') {
      checkBoxes.disabled = false;
    } else {
      checkBoxes.disabled = true;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('send-product').addEventListener('change', switchProduct);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwkgsuq1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to **loop your `checkboxes` Array collection**.

plain JS is not jQuery, therefore "`checkBoxes.disabled = false;`" **will not work**.
**Instead**:

```
for(var i=0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].disabled = false;
}
```

So your code simplified could look like:

```js
function switchProduct() {
  var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id^="parts-cb"]');
  var selectBox = document.getElementById('send-product');
  for(var i=0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].disabled = selectBox.value == 'wall-mounted';
  }
}
document.getElementById('send-product').addEventListener('change', switchProduct);
switchProduct();
```

```html
<select name="send_product" id="send-product">
  <option value="wall-mounted" selected>Wall-mounted (Default)</option>
  <option value="freestanding">Freestanding</option>
  <option value="third_party">Third Party</option>
</select><br><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="parts-cb1" value="1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="parts-cb2" value="1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="parts-cb3" value="1">
```

Comment: Thanks, the .disabled part has worked for me with plain JS before, but fair enough I didn't realize I had to loop it!

Comment: @Matthew :) yes, loop is needed unless you write your own micro-ala-jQuery-library to handle that for you... Also I know the `if/else` you have works, but it's the same if you directly go for a boolean like I did (so you don't have to repeat two times a for loop in every statement...)! Thumbs up! You're welcome! thx